# base keyword in json response of an api

Tags: c#, json, radix, asp.net-web-api

I have an api which returns the json as 
`{
  "timestamp": 1372741243,
  "base": "USD"
}`

I would like to call this using

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/latest.json?app_id=your_api_id").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var curr = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Currency>().Result;
        }
```

Now, the base in the api cannot be parsed as I cannot have base property in the Currency class, as base is a key-word. Any suggestions to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with adding prefix "@" before the parameter name `base`

```
public string @base { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* have a property named `base`, you just need to prefix the identifier with an `@` sign. From the [C# Language Specification, 2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx):

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier.

Try declaring your `Currency` like this:

```
public class Currency
{
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    ...
}
```